# Where to find latest OpenOffice dictionaries?

Tags: openoffice.org

I use Open Office dictionaries for spell checking in my application.

Can anyone tell me, what is the best place to find latest dictionaries? By dictionaries I mean *.dic and *.aff files.

Let's say, I managed to find some dictionaries here: http://wps-community.org/download/dicts/
I found some dictionaries here and there on the web. But is there any official source, which would let me download the latest dictionaries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dictionaries are most likely distributed as [Extensions](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Extensions).

Check out the website [extensions.openoffice.org](http://extensions.openoffice.org/) for the desired language(s).
After download you can install them by double-clicking, or -from within OpenOffice- with menu: `Tools>Extension Manager...>Add...`

At least the dictionary extensions should work with all flavours of OOo (Apache / Libre).